# Aligning and spacing of texts of buttons in a flextable using GAS

Tags: css, google-apps-script

In a flextable I create rows with buttons in the first column showing the number of each row, and textboxes in other columns.
I would like to reduce space between rows to a minimum.

```
var btnField = app.createButton(numRow).setId(fieldId).setSize(20, 20)
  .setStyleAttribute('marginBottom', 3).setStyleAttribute('marginTop', 0)
  .setStyleAttribute('fontSize', 8).setText(numRow)); 

flextable.setCellSpacing(1).setCellPadding(1); //Minimum distance between rows ??
```

Problem regarding the buttons is that the texts are not in the middle of the buttons vertically. I cannot reduce the size of the buttons (using `.setSize(20, 18)` or so) as text will become outside the buttons at the bottom.

What styleattributes should I use to position the text of the buttons in the middle of the buttons vertically, right alligned with a small marginRight?   The buttons itself should not exceed the size of the textboxes in order to minimize distances between rows.

If I have to use settings on the flextable, that will be OK as well of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Style attributes should be written using camelCase, use `fontSize` instead of `fontsize` and you'll get this :

[image]

which is nicely centered.

---

edit : I made a few tests on button text alignment and the results are a bit surprising ...
code and illustration below show that only horizontal alignment is doable on text content and that paddingTop applies but has side effects the other widgets as well

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('test buttons');
  var btn1 = app.createButton('test Button1').setPixelSize(200,60).setStyleAttributes({'fontFamily': 'serif','fontWeight': 'bold','fontSize':'14pt','text-align':'right'});
  var btn2 = app.createButton('test Button2').setPixelSize(200,30).setStyleAttributes({'fontSize':'12pt','textAlign':'left'});
  var btn3 = app.createButton('test Button3').setPixelSize(200,16).setStyleAttributes({'fontSize':'8pt','padding':'0px'});
  var btn4 = app.createButton('test Button4').setPixelSize(200,60).setStyleAttributes({'fontSize':'8pt','paddingTop':'30px'});
  app.add(btn1).add(btn2).add(btn3).add(btn4);
  return app;
}
```

[image]

A combination od padding and verticalAlignment can give interesting results, see below :

```
  var btn4 = app.createButton('testButton4').setPixelSize(200,60).setStyleAttributes({'fontSize':'8pt','paddingTop':'30px','vertical-align':'-11px'});
```

[image]

Comment: Works indeed, thanks. But the basic question of 'how to position the text vertically on the button' remains (answer not needed now).